# Downloaded the latest Xcode, but it's still using iOS SDK 4.3

Tags: xcode, ios5

when i go to Xcode -> preferences, under the documentation tab, there is the option to check for updates, and it says i'm on 4.3 SDK, but then tells me no updates available... 
i'm part of the developer program, using Lion OS... 
and if I try to download the latest Xcode (with SDK 5) from the app store, it tells me it's installed already.

what am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall all your Xcode's then just download the one you want?

Comment: @iBrad Apps - I thought about that but I'd also like to get to the root of the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation tab of the preferences will allow you to update the **documentation**.
It won't update Xcode, nor the SDKs.

To do so, you have two options:

1. You downloaded Xcode from the Mac AppStore:
   Simply update from there, an runs the Xcode installer again.
2. You downloaded Xcode from your developer account, on developer.apple.com:
   Log in, and download the latest Xcode installer. Once downloaded, install it.

Comment: 1. The App store will not allow me to install the latest Xcode with SDK 5.0, the download icon says "installed" 2. developer.apple.com always takes me through to the app store: please refer to point 1 ;-)

Comment: Note that the AppStore update actually updates the installer, in /Applications, not Xcode. You need to install again after an update.

Comment: Thanks @Macmade, I knew I was going to look silly at the end of this.